# Insert video in database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-insert

Given below is the query for inserting a video in a mySql database.

```
insert into media(name,data) values ('image', load_file('C:\ao.mp4'))
```

The table has 2 columns, name and data where data has BLOB data type. The first column is added to the table, but the second column returns null.

I have read the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14704559/how-to-insert-image-in-mysql-databasetable), but it is not working.

Comment: what kind of blob u hav? TINYBLOB, BLOB, MEDIUMBLOB, LONGBLOB=?

Comment: BLOB, the normal data type. Do I need LONGBLOB?

Comment: maybe its the problem.... you should try it.

Answer (score 2):

**Table creation:**

```
 CREATE TABLE media  (
               GAME_ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
               name VARCHAR (20),
               VIDEO  LONGBLOB );
```

Your insert query would be similar to this

```
INSERT INTO media values ('File_Name',LOAD_FILE("C:\\Users\\Public\\Videos\\Sample Video\\ao.mp4"));
```

> Result of load_file() was larger than max_allowed_packet (1048576)

You probably have to change it for both the client (you are running to do the import) AND the daemon mysqld that is running and accepting the import.

For the client, you can specify it on the command line:

```
mysql --max_allowed_packet=100M -u root -p database < dump.sql
```

Also, change the my.cnf or my.ini file under the mysqld section and set
max_allowed_packet=100M or you could run these commands in a MySQL console connected to that same server:

```
set global net_buffer_length=1000000; 
set global max_allowed_packet=1000000000;
```

(Use a very large value for the packet size.)

**To locate .ini File**

To configure the client and utility applications, create a new my.ini file in the Windows installation directory. More info  [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-config-wizard-starting.html)

Comment: I am on windows, so I just have to try these commands on the command line, right?

Comment: @PrakharMohanSrivastava this should be done mysql commandline prompt

Answer (score 1):

I think you hav 2 options:

1. Create multiple fields: VIDEO1, VIDEO2, etc... and split the video code on them.
2. Increase the max_allowed_packet: [source link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062496/how-to-change-max-allowed-packet-size)

> Change in the my.ini file. Include the single line under [mysqld] in your file
>
> max_allowed_packet=500M
>
> now restart the MySQL service and you are done

[How to locate my.ini file.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/mysql-config-wizard-file-location.html)