# MySQL LOAD_FILE returns NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, chmod, chown, mysql-loadfile

I want to get SQL *LOAD_FILE* function to work and have read every single question/answer + documentation about this, but here is what's been happening.

When I want to *LOAD_FILE* from my home directory:

```
mysql> SELECT LOAD_FILE('/home/myuser/somefile.txt');
+----------------------------+
| LOAD_FILE('/home/myuser/somefile.txt') |
+----------------------------+
| NULL                       |
+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So after getting this, I thought maybe the problem is that MySQL cannot access my home directory. And I tried running this, which worked fine:

```
SELECT LOAD_FILE('/etc/mysql/my.cnf');
```

Then `SELECT LOAD_FILE('/etc/passwd');` worked fine as well.

So I said gotcha, it's a file/folder read/ownership permission problem. So, I moved my file into /etc/mysql/ but then it still didn't work. I've tried `chown mysql:mysql somefile.txt` but still, I had no luck:

```
mysql> SELECT LOAD_FILE('/etc/mysql/somefile.txt');
+----------------------------+
| LOAD_FILE('/etc/mysql/somefile.txt') |
+----------------------------+
| NULL                       |
+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

P.S.
**1.** All files are readable by all user groups, so no need to chmod. But I've even tried *chmod 777* if you'd like to ask.
**2.** I checked, secure-file-priv variable is not set up in MySQL, so no, LOAD_FILE is not restricted to any path.

Any ideas what might be the problem here?

Comment: Do your file have any data?

Comment: @Rahul Yes, it does. I put a sentence or two in it. Less than 2 KB in total.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found out that it has to do with AppArmor. I disabled AppArmor for MySQL and it worked.
For people having the same problem, please read here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-howto-disable-apparmor-commands/

Comment: Alternate steps to disable apparmor that worked for me on Linux Mint 18 - this stops apparmor service from running ever again, but doesn't delete apparmor package from the servers:

    # /etc/init.d/apparmor stop
    # /etc/init.d/apparmor teardown
    # update-rc.d -f apparmor remove
    # service apache2 restart
    # service mysql restart

Comment: If placed in original folder of `select @@GLOBAL.secure_file_priv;` (in my case it was - `/var/lib/mysql-files`) instead of changing it, then apparmor disabling is not needed

Answer (score 5):

Per [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file)

> To use this function, the file must be located on the server host.
>
> You must specify the full path name to the file.
>
> You must have the FILE privilege.
>
> The file must be readable by all
>
> File size should be less than `max_allowed_packet` bytes.
>
> If the secure_file_priv system variable is set to a nonempty directory
>   name, the file to be loaded must be located in that directory.
>
> If the file does not exist or cannot be read because one of the
>   preceding conditions is not satisfied, **the function returns NULL**.

So check all the above mentioned condition satisfies.

**EDIT:**

Not sure whether you understood properly ..

1. make sure the file parent directory have execute permission. So if `somefile.txt` sits under `myuser` directory; you must have execute have permission on `myuser` directory.
2. `You must have the FILE privilege.` means the FILE privilege must be granted explicitly using `GRANT FILE on . TO user@localhost`
3. Flush the privilege
4. Logout and Login back and check whether it's working or not.

See this post [MySQL LOAD_FILE() loads null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18069054/mysql-load-file-loads-null-values)

Comment: yes, I've read the documentation and checked all above conditions in advance. I'm pretty sure the file cannot be read (related to the last condition), but I don't know why. It just cannot read the file for some reason.

Comment: That's great. What is the value of `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet'`?

Comment: mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';
+--------------------+------------+
| Variable_name      | Value      |
+--------------------+------------+
| max_allowed_packet | 1073741824 |
+--------------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: @Emir, that fine then. Check edited answer and varify those points

Comment: Answer for your EDIT:
1. Yes, the folder has execute permission. I've even tried putting this file under /etc/mysql/ which MySQL has all the access by default.
2. I'm logged into MySQL as root, so yes I've checked and have FILE privilege (and all other privileges).

Comment: apparmor should go into the list, too

Answer (score 4):

So I been banging my head against this issue with finally found to to resolve it:

```
mysql> select LOAD_FILE('/var/www/upload/test.zip');
+---------------------------------------+
| LOAD_FILE('/var/www/upload/test.zip') |
+---------------------------------------+
| NULL                                  |
+---------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The problem is the **secure_file_priv** is not set.   To see where it is pointed to do the following query:

Perform query:

```
select @@GLOBAL.secure_file_priv;
```

To point to the area that you are looking to pull file
What I did was to add the following to the end mysqld.conf

```
secure_file_priv =  /var/www/upload.
```

Restarted mysql and test with

```
mysql> select LOAD_FILE('/var/www/upload/test.zip');
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: This was it for me. Only files in this location could be loaded into the database. Thanks.

Comment: You have to add `secure_file_priv =  /var/www/upload` exactly under `[mysqld]` line in the file `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` and not at the "end", this incomplete information made me waste a few hours, hope I helped somebody 

Also the answer provided by @Emir has to be followed at the same time, that is turnoff "apparmor" for "mysql"

Answer (score 2):

I'd the same problem with Fedora Linux while trying add images to a blob field.

I solved coping the files to the directory `/var/lib/mysql/images` and giving the command:

`chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/images`

Answer (score 0):

Load data infile file_name... is the proper command for MySQL. And since you didn't give an example of the data in your file I can't show you know to exactly use it. There are variables to handle delimiters and end of line characteristics. Good luck.