# MySQL LOAD_FILE returns null on some files

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu-20.04

I'm trying to load a `/etc/flag` file using mysql `LOAD_FILE` function, but it returns `null`. I've created this file by copying passwd file like this `cp /etc/passwd /etc/flag`, then I've given it permissions that are exactly the same as the permissions of passwd file `chmod 644 /etc/flag`.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1806 Dec 15 18:29 /etc/flag
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1806 Dec 15 18:04 /etc/passwd
```

The result of `SELECT LOAD_FILE('/etc/passwd')` is the contents of the passwd file.

The result of `SELECT LOAD_FILE('/etc/flag')` is `NULL`

What can be the other difference between `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/flag` that one loads and the other does not?

My MySQL version is `mysql  Ver 8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))`

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24459149/6843158) help ?

Comment: Yeap, that was it. Strangely I thought that turning the AppArmor service using `service apparmor stop` would do the same, but it didn't. Thank you.