# Insert image into SQL Server database fix some errors

Tags: sql-server, database, image, insert

I'm trying to storage in my database an image, so I have created a column named images in a table of my database with "blob" type.

Then I have found on the internet that if I want to add an image to my database i have to write this little code :

```
INSERT INTO tableName (ImageColumn) 
    SELECT BulkColumn 
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'image..Path..here', Single_Blob) AS img
```

But when I execute this code, I get some errors and I'm trying to fix that before asking a question here but after 3 hours of research I'm here to asking you guys for some help.

Here are the error I get:

> Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 73)
>   Unexpected token. (near "Bulk" at position 75)
>   Unexpected token. (near "'image..Path..here'" at position 80)
>   Unexpected token. (near "," at position 99)
>   Unexpected token. (near "Single_Blob" at position 101)
>   Unexpected token. (near ")" at position 112)
>   Unrecognized keyword. (near "as" at position 114)
>   Unexpected token. (near "img" at position 117)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is correct for Microsoft T-SQL. The error message looks more like MySql. The message says that the syntax is incorrect, not that there is a problem with the execution.

Comment: aah okay i didn't now this, i thinked this syntax is for Mysql and if you now how to do this in Mysql can you help me ? and sorry for my english if it's not good

Comment: My MySQL time is already a few years back, but maybe this helps you: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14704559/how-to-insert-image-in-mysql-databasetable).