# I am trying to insert an image as blob in database using mysqlClient only, but it returns NULL in table

Tags: mysql

When I run this query it only inserts `NULL` into the `image` column:

```
insert into imgblob('image') values(LOAD_FILE("C:\Users\Desktop\apple.png"));
```

Comment: The conditions under which LOAD_FILE returns NULL are listed in the manual; resp. the conditions that must be met for this to work - so go check. And btw., binary image data does usually not belong into the database, the file system is the much more appropriate storage location for that.

Comment: Not sure you may load the resource like that, try this INSERT INTO imgblob (image) VALUES(LOAD_FILE('c://apple.png'));

Answer (score 0):

Try LOAD_FILE('C:/Users/Desktop/apple.png') i.e "/" instead of "\"
check this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14704709/5246822)

Comment: i am still getting NULL

Comment: @ipk try using a single quote 'C:/Users/Desktop/apple.png' instead of double quote "C:\Users\Desktop\apple.png" if its still NULL can you show me your table structure for imgblob.

Comment: +---------------------------+
| image                     |
+---------------------------+
| C:UsersKH9277Desktopapple |
| NULL                      |
| NULL                      |
| NULL                      |
| NULL                      |
| NULL                      |
| NULL                      |
| NULL                      |
| NULL                      |
| NULL                      |
| NULL                      |
| NULL                      |
| NULL                      |
| NULL                      |
+---------------------------+
14 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: @ipk i cant see the data type for the column image and i m sure you know the datatype should be "blob". Run this query -->  alter table imgblob modify image longblob; to make your column blob compartible then try your insert query again.