# Connecting my image folder to mysql server database

Tags: python, mysql

Currently I am working on my python project on face recognition. There for training my database I need to connect my folder of images to MYSQL server but I am new to this.
I have created a database but don't know how to create tables that represents my image.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your qestion is already answered [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14704559/how-to-insert-image-in-mysql-databasetable)

```
INSERT INTO xx_BLOB(ID,IMAGE) VALUES(1,LOAD_FILE('E:/Images/jack.jpg'));
```