# Insert img into database MySQL using codelgniter php frame work

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert img in mySQL database.
I'm using codelgniter php frame so code is must be in the MVC format

How it possible?

Comment: You have two basic options: You can hash the image using something like `base64_encode` and insert that, or you can insert the location of the image on the filesystem.

Comment: NO i want to insert the image ( any file ) in the database i know the code of display but i can't insert img in database it can be done in codelgniter frame work only

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14704559/how-to-insert-image-in-mysql-databasetable